# SQL Server Procedure -Recorrer tabla, comparar cada elemento obtenido y decidir hacer insert o no

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo una tabla (llamada PermisosPRE) con 2 columnas (`Name`, `id_ref`) que contiene 8 mil y pico registros con la relación de 1rol-1proceso, la columna `Name` contiene esos roles posibles en formato `varchar`, la columna `id_ref` contiene los nombres de procesos en formato `varchar`.

Necesito crear un procedimiento que me recorra esa tabla y por cada registro:

1) Obtener el id asignado `_roles.ID` a ese rol en `_roles.name`.
2) Obtener el id asignado `descTree.ID` a cada proceso en `descTree.id_ref`.
3) Comprobar si existe el rol `PermisosPRE.Name` y tiene permisos sobre el proceso en la base de datos actual `descRolProcess.id_a= _roles.ID y descRolProcess.id_b = descTree.ID`
          a) Si ya tiene permisos, no se hace nada
          b) Si no tiene permisos, se establecen, insertando un registro en la tabla `descRolProcess`.

```
Insert into descRolProcess (id_a, id_b) values (id del rol '_roles.ID',id del proceso 'descTree.ID'
```

Por ahora tengo esto pero estoy bastante liado y no se como seguir:

```
    -- Variables
    DECLARE @rol_elemento_actual AS VARCHAR(80)
    DECLARE @proceso_elemento_actual AS VARCHAR(80)

-- Declaracion del cursor BUSCADOR.
    DECLARE BUSCADOR CURSOR FOR
        --Relacion roles-permisos definidos en la BD antes de la migración
        SELECT qPRE.Name, qPRE.id_ref
        FROM PermisosPRE qPRE       
    OPEN BUSCADOR

-- Recorremos el puntero y cargamos en la variable el valor del elemento actual
      FETCH NEXT FROM BUSCADOR
      INTO @rol_elemento_actual, @proceso_elemento_actual
          WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
            BEGIN
            -- Obtener el identificador del rol de la tabla temporal(PermisosPRE) en la base de datos actual (_roles.Name)
                SET @rol_elemento_actual =
                    (SELECT qR.Name 
                    FROM _roles qR
                    INNER JOIN PermisosPRE qP ON qP.Name = qR.Name
                    GROUP BY qR.Name)
            -- Obtener el identificador del proceso de la tabla temporal en la base de datos actual (descTree.id_ref)
                SET @proceso_elemento_actual = 
                    (SELECT qRP.id_b, qPPW.id_ref
                    FROM descRolProcess qRP             
                    INNER JOIN descTree qT ON qT.id = qRP.id_b
                    INNER JOIN PermisosPRE qPPW ON qPPW.id_ref = qT.id_Ref
                    GROUP BY qRP.id_b, qPPW.id_ref)

            -- Comprobar si existe el rol y/o tiene permisos sobre el proceso en la base de datos actual (descRolProcess.id_a= id del rol y descRolProcess.id_b = id del proceso
                IF (@rol_elemento_actual IS NOT NULL)
                    -- Si ya tiene permisos, no se hace nada, ) Si no tiene permisos, se establecen, insertando un registro en la tabla descRolProcess.                 
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO descRolProcess (id_a, id_b) 
                        VALUES (id-del-roll,id-del-proceso) 
                        RETURN
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        -- NADA
                        RETURN 
                    END               
            -- Avanzamos al siguiente elemento
            FETCH NEXT FROM BUSCADOR
            INTO @id_name_elemento_actual, @id_ref_elemento_actual
        END

    -- Cerramos el cursor
        CLOSE BUSCADOR
    -- Liberamos la memoria
    DEALLOCATE BUSCADOR
```

¿Me podéis ayudar?
--Obtener el Id nuevo  (_roles.ID) del rol antiguo (PermisosPRE.Name)

```
SELECT qR.ID, qR.Name 
FROM _roles qR
INNER JOIN PermisosPRE qPPW ON qPPW.Name = qR.Name
GROUP BY qR.ID, qR.Name
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que tu procedimiento no hace bien?

Comment: Estoy casi seguro de que esto se puede hacer sin un cursor. Sin embargo, estoy un poco confundido sobre donde salen los valores. Comparte un poco de datos de muestra y los resultados esperados desde esos datos. También incluye la estructura de las tablas involucradas.

Answer (score 0):

Tratando de entender tu proceso y las tablas y columnas con nombres confusos (¿Por qué mezclar inglés y español?), creo que todo se puede reducir a un solo INSERT usando la clausula EXCEPT. Dejo un ejemplo según lo que comprendí, pero es posible que haya que ajustar las consultas.

```
INSERT INTO descRolProcess (id_a, id_b) 
SELECT qR.ID, qR.Name 
FROM _roles qR
INNER JOIN PermisosPRE qPPW ON qPPW.Name = qR.Name
EXCEPT
SELECT id_a, id_b
FROM descRolProcess;
```